# What does the standard say about double comparision of a single variable in a single if statement?

Tags: c++

I tried this code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/tdo29h) and on Visual Studio 2013:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    if(4 < x < 6)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces a runtime error on ideone but works perfectly fine on VS.

What does the standard say about this nonconsistent behaviour. I know there are compilation warnings but I'm wondering why this isn't natively/officially supported?

Comment: Did you check the return value on VS? It should return 1.

Comment: It works fine on ideone. The "runtime error" means that your program is returning a value from `main` that isn't `0`. That is, your program is reporting that there is an error.

Answer (score 12):

This is valid code in both C and C++, but does not do what you meant.  It is the same as:

```
bool temp = (4 < x);
if (temp < 6) // always true
     return 1;  // this is EXIT_FAILURE
// dead code here returning EXIT_SUCCESS
```

The result of relational operators on primitive types is `bool` (in C++, `int` in C), and `bool` gets promoted to `int` for the subsequent comparison, giving the value `0` or `1`, always.

Since both `0` and `1` are less than `6`, the condition is always true.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to do it in that order? It would make sense if it does, but could an optimizing compiler decide to do `bool temp = (x < 6); if(4 < temp)` instead?

Comment: @wolfPack88: The order is guaranteed by the associativity rules.  If you had `f() < x < g()` you wouldn't know whether `f()` or `g()` got called first, but `x` would be compared to the result of `f()` first.

Comment: probably should add that if( 4 < x and x < 6 ) does what he wants

Comment: good to know that :) Can accept in 5 min, and wow, this answer literally exploded in ups

Comment: No, not literally. Figuratively. The opposite of literally.

Answer (score 5):

Ben Voigt's answer is correct, of course, but I want to address the "runtime error" part of the question:

It's works just as fine in Visual Studio as it does on ideone. [The `return 1;` is reported by ideone as a `runtime error`](http://ideone.com/7F7bMv). Visual Studio has the same return value; it just doesn't complain as loudly as ideone does.

Comment: Indeed, because `EXIT_SUCCESS` in `stdlib.h` is defined as `0`, and this code takes the other branch.